# CUDA programming for ODE solver using thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, tuples, ode, thrust

I am trying to solve ODE with 6 variable in CUDA using thrust. My program is here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>


 #include <thrust/device_vector.h>
 #include <thrust/reduce.h>
 #include <thrust/functional.h>
  #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

  #include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/thrust/thrust_algebra.hpp>
  #include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/thrust/thrust_operations.hpp>
  #include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/thrust/thrust_resize.hpp>



   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


   typedef double value_type;

typedef thrust::device_vector< value_type > state_type;

const value_type n1 = 10.0;



 struct Goodwin_system
{
    struct Goodwin_functor
    {
        template< class T >
        __host__ __device__
        void operator()( T t ) const
        {

        value_type x1 = thrust::get< 0 >( t );
        value_type x2 = thrust::get< 1 >( t );
        value_type x3 = thrust::get< 2 >( t );
        value_type x4 = thrust::get< 3 >( t );
        value_type x5 = thrust::get< 4 >( t );
        value_type x6 = thrust::get< 5 >( t );

        value_type a  = thrust::get< 6 >( t );// For differnt values of a we will get different ODE

       thrust::get< 7 >( t ) = a * (77.3*(pow(0.001,n1)/(pow(0.001,n1) + pow(x3,n1))) - x1);
       thrust::get< 8 >( t ) = a * (x1-x2);
       thrust::get< 9 >( t ) = a * (x2-x3);
       thrust::get< 10 >( t ) = a * (x3-x4);
       thrust::get< 11 >( t ) = a * (x4-x5);
       thrust::get< 12 >( t ) = a * (x5-x6);
    }
};

Goodwin_system( size_t N , const state_type &aa ) // aa is for different values of the parameter a
: m_N( N ) , m_aa( aa ) { }

template< class State , class Deriv >
void operator()(  const State &x , Deriv &dxdt , value_type t ) const
{
    thrust::for_each(
            thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
                    boost::begin( x ) ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 2 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 3 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 4 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 5 * m_N ,
                    m_aa.begin() ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + m_N ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 3 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 4 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 5 * m_N ) ) ,
            thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple(
                    boost::begin( x ) + m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 2 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 3 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 4 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 5 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( x ) + 6 * m_N ,
                    m_aa.end() ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + m_N ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 2 * m_N ,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 3 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 4 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 5 * m_N,
                    boost::begin( dxdt ) + 6 * m_N)) ,
                    Goodwin_functor() );
}

size_t m_N;
const state_type &m_aa;
   };


size_t N;

 void write_ans( const state_type &x , const double t )// For writing the    results
{

 cout<<t<<"\t";

 for( size_t i=0 ; i<6*N ; ++i ) 
     {
    cout<<x[i]<<"\t";
     }
     cout<<endl;

 }

 const value_type dt = 0.1;
 const value_type t_max = 1000.0;

 int main( int argc , char* argv[] )
 {


      N = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1000;// for 1000 oscillator

  vector< value_type > aa_host( N );

   const value_type aa_min = value_type(0.01);

   for( size_t i=0 ; i<N ; ++i )

      aa_host[i] =(i+1)*aa_min;// Generate differnt a values for each iteration

    state_type aa = aa_host;

     //[ thrust_Goodwin_parameters_integration

  state_type x( 6 * N );

// initialize x,y,z

thrust::fill( x.begin() , x.end() , value_type(0.2) );



typedef runge_kutta4< state_type , value_type , state_type , value_type ,
          thrust_algebra , thrust_operations > stepper_type;


Goodwin_system Goodwin(N , aa);


integrate_const( stepper_type() , Goodwin , x , value_type(0.1) , t_max , dt, write_ans);

return 0;
   }
```

When I try to compile it, error showing

"error: no instance of overloaded function "thrust::make_tuple" matches the argument list"

I could solve ODE with 4 variable without any error. Is tuple only support up to 10

element? What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, a `thrust::tuple` is templated only [up to a maximum of 10 elements](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__tuple.html)

Answer (score 1):

As is clearly defined in the [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1tuple.html), `thrust::tuple` is statically templated up to a maximum of 10 entries. Short of re-implementing your own version with more entries, this is a non-negotiable limit of the class.

Comment: So, how to solve an ode with more than 5 variable in CUDA?

Comment: Don't use the zip operator and tuples. Use a type of your own